# Parsing and splitting files based on the string

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a very large file (hence .ReadLines) which I need to efficiently and quickly parse and split into other files. For each line which contains a keyword I need to copy that line and append to a specific file. This is what I have so far, the script runs but the files aren't getting populated.

```
$filename = "C:\dev\powershell\test1.csv"

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
    if    ($line | %{$_ -match "Apple"}){Out-File -Append Apples.txt}
    elseif($line | %{$_ -match "Banana"}){Out-File -Append Bananas.txt}
    elseif($line | %{$_ -match "Pear"}){Out-File -Append Pears.txt}
}
```

Example content of the csv file:

```
Apple,Test1,Cross1
Apple,Test2,Cross2
Apple,Test3,Cross3
Banana,Test4,Cross4
Pear,Test5,Cross5
```

I want Apples.txt to contain:

```
Apple,Test1,Cross1
Apple,Test2,Cross2
Apple,Test3,Cross3
```

Comment: Change $_ to $line

Comment: @EBGreen this doesn't help, the files are not being created/appended to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

Your `if` conditions don't need `%`/`foreach-object` - `-match` will do on its own:

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
  if($line -match "Apple"){
    # output to apple.txt
  }
  else($line -match "Banana"){
    # output to banana.txt
  }
  # etc...
}
```

The files aren't getting populated because you're not actually sending any output to `Out-File`:

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
  if($line -match "Apple"){
    # send $line to the file
    $line |Out-File apple.txt -Append
  }
  # etc...
}
```

---

If your files are really massive and you expect a lot of matching lines, I'd recommend using a `StreamWriter` for the output files - otherwise `Out-File` will be opening and closing the file all the time:

```
$OutFiles = @{
  'apple'  = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $PWD\apples.txt
  'banana' = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $PWD\bananas.txt
  'pear'   = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $PWD\pears.txt
}

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
  foreach($keyword in $OutFiles.Keys){
    if($line -match $keyword){
      $OutFiles[$keyword].WriteLine($line)
      continue
    }
  }
}

foreach($Writer in $OutFiles.Values){
  try{
    $Writer.Close()
  }
  finally{
    $Writer.Dispose()
  }
}
```

This way you also only have to maintain the `$OutFiles` hashtable if you need to update the keywords for example.